C wire connection at boiler
boiler modelI have a spare blue wire to use as C. Just confused where to connect to my steam boiler. I see an extra lug but not sure if it’s for C wire. Thanks

it is marked COM

@DIY75 where do you see "COM"?  I don't see it.

Neil it would be helpful if you include the model of the boiler, and a picture of the wiring diagram that is probably glued to the inside of a panel or something like that.    Try measuring voltage R-B, R-T (for each T) and B-T with the thermostat in open and then in closed state.   Hopefully you'll find B is your common.  Otherwise you might need to go to the back of the board.

@jay613 it is partially obstructed by the wire
